# Spring 4 Asynchronous Job Executor and Manager

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-batch

All,
  I have some client code that needs to execute tasks that might be long running. A user will want to upload a video for processing which could take a long time and/or possibly fail. Another user might want to upload a small pic which could finish quickly or also fail. In all cases I need to be able to update the client code with some sort progress as the job moves along. Is there a Spring 4 solution for this kind of pattern. I have found many pub/sub solutions but they were all several years old. I am hoping this type of problem is now common enough to have a structured solution.